# Dialogs don't work after using attrs

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I decided to add Night Theme to my app, so I replaced `@colors` with `?attrs`.
So I have an `activity` with `toolbar`, from which I'm trying to open a dialog with some settings. Dialogs do not wish to open and cause crash.

Logs:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:424)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:204)
    at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:602)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:426)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23165)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23165)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23165)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23165)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23165)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23165)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:720)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23165)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2689)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1528)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1826)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7125)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:935)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:682)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0401a5 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:546)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3542)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:959)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:869)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:865)
        ... 52 more
```

And here is the XML it doesn't like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="?attr/vk_white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/setup_home"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/headline"
        android:background="?attr/vk_grey_color"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/headline">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/warning_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="?attr/warning"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/warning_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_warning"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/warning_icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="?attr/vk_white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/warning_home"
                android:padding="8dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/whose_show"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/show_photos_of"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/whose_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/whose_show"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/edit_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/whose_spinner"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/how_many"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/counter_edit"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/setup_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/whose_spinner"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/setup_list" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sort_by_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sorttext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sort" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_below="@id/sorttext"
                android:id="@+id/sort_spinner"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/sort_by_name"
            android:background="?attr/vk_grey_color"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/savePrefsHome"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've already tried to remove `@style` parts from `TextViews`, But it didn't help. Has anyone faced similar problem? What is wrong?

**EDIT**

Dialog is started like this:

```
HomeDialog settings = new HomeDialog();
settings.showDialog(activity, getWhoseSelected(), getSortSelected());
```

And the showDialog method just uses this data for spiners' setup.
Here is styles XML as well:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3e4160</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#203e58</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#5f6cde</item>
    <item name="homepage">#f4f4f4</item>
    <item name="home">#e4e4e4</item>
    <item name="darkgrey">#b4b4b4</item>
    <item name="lighty">#fcfcfc</item>
    <item name="darkest">#5e5e5e</item>
    <item name="warning">#a8b2d4</item>
    <item name="notification">#b8abd4</item>
    <item name="pano">#1f4490</item>
    <item name="pinky">#ff6b6b</item>
    <item name="navColor">#203e58</item>
    <item name="vk_black">#000</item>
    <item name="vk_grey_color">#f0f2f5</item>
    <item name="vk_white">#fff</item>
    <item name="black_overlay">#66000000</item>
</style>

<!-- Dark application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme_NightMode" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#252525</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#161616</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#5f6cde</item>
    <item name="homepage">#252525</item>
    <item name="home">#3b3b3b</item>
    <item name="darkgrey">#b4b4b4</item>
    <item name="lighty">#fcfcfc</item>
    <item name="darkest">#5e5e5e</item>
    <item name="warning">#a8b2d4</item>
    <item name="notification">#b8abd4</item>
    <item name="pano">#1f4490</item>
    <item name="pinky">#ff6b6b</item>
    <item name="navColor">#9e9e9e</item>
    <item name="vk_black">#000</item>
    <item name="vk_grey_color">#f0f2f5</item>
    <item name="vk_white">#fff</item>
    <item name="black_overlay">#66000000</item>
</style>
```

Dialog is being built inside HomeDialog class:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
// some actions with the data
dialog.show();
```

Comment: How do you start the dialog? Do this via the activity context, which contains the themes and knows your used attributes. Could you add your style xml?

Comment: @KennySeyffarth can you give me example how do I do this with context? For now the dialog is being constructed with the data and uses dialog.show() to show itself.

Comment: Did you prepared the possible attributes in your project? like an "attr.xml" file and named the attributes like "<attr name="an_attribute_color_name" format="color"/>"? Did you set the correct dialog style in your themes? like 
    "<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/aTheme</item>" which takes care about your custom attributes?

Comment: @KennySeyffarth i have attrs file with color names, but I use custom XML for dialog, so do I still need to use theme for it? Dialog's xml is clipped to the topic.

Comment: I think so, if you check the constructor of a Dialog, 
"if (createContextThemeWrapper) {
            if (themeResId == ResourceId.ID_NULL) {
                final TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
                context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.dialogTheme, outValue, true);
                themeResId = outValue.resourceId;
            }
            mContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeResId);
        } else {
            mContext = context;
        }"

Comment: you simply should add the missing attributes into the dialog theme, which you prepare in your styles. (I'm honest, i did not played so often with custom attributes. But this would be my first check, if i have such kinds of problems)